# Load icon pic without being cropped?

Tags: html, xhtml, xhtml-transitional

Noob here. At what size i.e. width and height should I load a small pic that represents an icon link i.e. Home, Sitemap icons. Is there a universal width and height that won't crop the image when it renders in different browsers? thanks, I usually set them at 88 x 88.

Comment: Why would any browser crop the picture?

Comment: the pic comes out missing a part for some reason. Is there a way to move the pic a bit away from the left border?

Comment: You should show the code you have. The problem is not the image's size.

Comment: <img src="images/site map.gif" alt="Site Map Compass" height="88" width="88" />

Comment: Not enough code--there's no reason why a single img tag by itself would become cropped. Show a *complete* example that displays the problem.

Comment: If you have a navigation bar or something, containing several images, at one point you're going to be out of space in the window. Is that what you're worried about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<img src="dog.jpg" alt="Image of a dog" title="A dog running happily around" height="42" width="42"><img src="dog.jpg" alt="Image of a dog" title="A dog running happily around" height="42" width="42">
```

make sure there is no space between the > < img tags

Answer (score 2):

No a browser will not crop an image. There is nothing to worry about this. If you are new to this i would advise you to get used into putting Alts, Title (for SEO - Search Engine Optimization) as well as the size of your images.

```
<img src="dog.jpg" alt="Image of a dog" title="A dog running happily around" height="42" width="42">
```

If your image appears cropped, that might be because of your CSS. On Chrome for example right click on the image and select 'Inspect'. Then check on the bottom left under the Styles tab to see if there is any style that affects your image. You can unclick the styles to see if one of these causes your image to get cropped. If that's the case just edit your css accordingly.

Comment: That's just what my prof. told me, that the image was cropped/missing parts.

Comment: You must provide us with an example or your full code. You can use http://jsfiddle.net/ to do that and give ur the link of your fiddle.
Just a quick question for noobies... Are you sure your image is 88x88 pixels? It can get cropped if it is not 88x88 and u set the size to that.